# How to handle Service References in Windows Phone 8 without Task-Based proxies

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-phone-8, service-reference

With so much emphasis on Task-Based asynchronous development, I was surprised to see that Service References in Windows Phone 8 do not support task-based implementations. Instead they use a "XYZCompleted" event-based asynchronous approach.

As a result, code like this is necessary: http://codepaste.net/fqyt47

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyService.Character>> GetCharactersAsync()
{
    var _Task = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<MyService.Character>>();
    var _Client = new MyService.ServiceClient();
    _Client.GetCharactersCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        var _Characters = e.Result as IEnumerable<MyService.Character>;
        if (e.Error != null && !_Task.TrySetException(e.Error))
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        else if (e.Cancelled && !_Task.TrySetCanceled())
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        else if (!_Task.TrySetResult(_Characters))
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    };
    _Client.GetCharactersAsync();

    return await _Task.Task;
}
```

However, **this feels wrong**. Is there a better, more elegant approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised Windows Phone 8 doesn't have `Task`-based reference creation.

That said, `TaskCompletionSource` [is the standard way of interoperating with various asynchronous patterns (including EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx).

Usually it's done with extension methods which are consumable by `await` but which are not `async` themselves:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<MyService.Character>> GetCharactersTaskAsync(this ServiceClient client)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<MyService.Character>>();
  client.GetCharactersCompleted += (s, e) =>
  {
    if (e.Error != null) tcs.SetException(e.Error);
    else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.SetCanceled();
    else tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
  };
  client.GetCharactersAsync();
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: The problem with an extension method like that is that you need one for every single operation. Seems to me that it's not generic enough to be a good extension method.

Comment: Since we only have generics in .NET and not templates, that's what we're stuck with. I have a [`TryCompleteFromEventArgs`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskCompletionSourceExtensions) in my AsyncEx library that helps with it, but it's not possible to write a fully generic EAP wrapper in C#. Or any .NET language.

Comment: Alright. That's fair. We'll see if anyone else has any clever approaches.